# How to dynamically assign each button to change color on click

Tags: react-native

I have a group of buttons as the following picture :

[image: 8 sample buttons]

I want to know how I can use react native to individually and dynamically change their color `onPress`

Answer (score 0):

use stateful component.

Because I avoided the class keyword, I would use recompose, add a new state using withState().
you need to call compose() with your button component.

during onPress, you can have something like,

```
onPress={ ()=> setStateColor(randomColor()) }
```

Comment: If I set this for all of them, won't clicking one, change all colors ?

Comment: @Hypothesis Indeed! You would need a state for each of your button. To make it simpler to handle each state, you could do a custom component for your button in which it would have its color state. By clicking on it, it would change its local state and therefore only himself!

Comment: each button will have their own colors.